# How to retrieve a cookie's value?

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I may be asking the wrong question but I am still fairly new to JavaScript. I need to create a cookie that will re-strict the number of usages a user has for an online product demo. In pseudo code, I assume it would be something like this:

```
if(readCookie('demo') == null){ 
 createCookie('demo','1',1);}  //Assuming the functions for setting a cookie and retrieving it have already been created.
else {
    readCookie('demo');
}

if demo cookie has value{
    increment the value by one
}
else if value exceeds 10 {
    alert message //I set this so I could test out the function
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+read+write+cookies

Comment: You should realize that it is trivial for a user to delete their cookie and play for as many times as they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page will tell you everything you need to know and even provides example functions for you to plug into your own code to make cookie handling very easy.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

If your open to using jQuery, you should look at the [jquery.cookie plugin.](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js)

Examples (via Documentation):

Create session cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire page:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null
```

Delete cookie by passing null as value:

```
$.cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by a user-comment, a cookie is not a good way to do this. You cannot enforce it.

That said, I wrote and maintain a JavaScript cookie API. Check it out at: http://code.google.com/p/cookies/ (It does NOT require jQuery, although it has extras built in if jQ is present).

Here is your pseudo code translated to use the lib: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/BGFQs/ (You'll see the alert after clicking "Run" enough times)